# How to assign integer values to based on id in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | a |
| 15 | b |
| 18 | c |
| 19 | d |
| 20 | e |
| 20 | f |

I want to create a select query with replaces the id value with integers starting from 1.

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |
| 4 | e |
| 4 | f |

This is my expectation. I am using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Then WHY did you tag MySQL? Tags are used to attract the correct audience for your question, not an angry mob

Comment: Sorry for that..

Comment: Have you tried `dense_rank()` ?

Comment: In other words, you want to rank the rows by the non-identifying `id` value? You can use `DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ID) as id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try an updateable CTE with the help of `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) dr
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET id = dr;
```